# Is the information in this blog incorrect?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, podcast

I just saw this [How terrifying is giving a conference talk? (Ep. 589)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/14/how-terrifying-is-giving-a-conference-talk-ep-589/) in The Over Flow blog at the right side of SO page.

I read through it and I am now curious about this part.

> A very special Lifeboat badge is awarded to Connell for answering his
> own question: Why does this SelectMany perform several SQL queries
> instead of a single join?.

I followed the linked question and answer, but was confused that the question and answer have little to no upvotes for it. I remember that [Lifeboat badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat)'s condition is not that so easy; so, I looked at the badge and see

> Answer score of 20 or more to a question score of -3 or less that goes
> on to receive a score of 3 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple
> times.

It does not match at all. I also checked if [Connell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369247/connell) actually got the badge. He does not.

Therefore, I am curious if this information is incorrect.

Comment: Could the badge have been lost since the podcast aired?

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike I don't think lifeboat can be lost. Even if it could, the question has never had -3 votes, and the answer has never had +20 votes. Unless 23 votes quietly disappeared without a single trace, there's absolutely no way it could've ever been true. This isn't an edge-case  where the answer dropped from +20 to +19 after the blog post was released. It has _never_ had close to +20

Comment: I wonder if the person who posted got confused

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike I doubt it. It's in the transcript too, mentioned by Ben Popper (who also misunderstands that nearly 300 views != nearly 300 people helped in that same paragraph).

Comment: So... someone who is unfamiliar with the network got it wrong, and the person he was talking to was too polite to correct him on live mike? This is my surprised face...

Comment: According to the [transcript for that podcast](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/how-terrifying-is-giving-a-conference-talk/transcript), that was the segment of the podcast where they *normally* thank someone who's earned the Lifeboat badge, but instead they just gave a shoutout to Connell for that self-answered question. So I think the episode notes for that podcast episode (in the blog post, and on the Simplecast page) just need to be updated accordingly. I'll follow up with the Marketing team.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good catch!

The episode notes have now been updated in the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/14/how-terrifying-is-giving-a-conference-talk-ep-589/) and on Simplecast to read:

> Thanks to [Connell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369247/connell) for answering his own question: [Why does this SelectMany perform several SQL queries instead of a single join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930586/why-does-this-selectmany-perform-several-sql-queries-instead-of-a-single-join).